# Issue with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with `setInterval`. I'm trying to make two buttons to increase or decrease `scrollLeft` property with a slide effect but it didn't work.

Here is my code below:

```
var x;
var scrollDiv = document.getElementById("army_selection");

var scrollLeft = document.getElementById("scroll_left");
scrollLeft.addEventListener("mouseover", dec_scroll, false);
scrollLeft.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){clearInterval(x);}, false);

var scrollRight = document.getElementById("scroll_right");
scrollRight.addEventListener("mouseover", inc_scroll, false);
scrollRight.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){clearInterval(x);}, false);


/* Functions */

function inc_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(scrollDiv.scrollLeft += 5, 1);
}

function dec_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(scrollDiv.scrollLeft -= 5, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, right now, `scrollDiv.scrollLeft += 5` is being executed once in your scroll functions, and the return value is being passed to the first parameter of `setInterval`. Because it is not a function, it wont be called again.

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) takes a function as its first parameter. Since `scrollDiv.scrollLeft += 5` is not a function, you need to wrap it in a function:

```
function inc_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(() => scrollDiv.scrollLeft += 5, 1);
}

function dec_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(() => scrollDiv.scrollLeft -= 5, 1);
}
```

Or if you prefer the old function format:

```
function inc_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(function() { scrollDiv.scrollLeft += 5 }, 1);
}

function dec_scroll() {
    x = setInterval(function() { scrollDiv.scrollLeft -= 5 }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! i hadn't notice i didn't put it in a function, thank a lot !